# Python bot aiogram регистрация хэндлеров

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

Проблема следующая - работает только самая первая функция, а последующие нет. Нашел информацию про регистрацию хэндлеров, но реализовать именно в этой ситуации так и не получилось. Как это можно исправить?
Код:

```
import logging
import os, json, string

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

# log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

#bot init
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot) 

#udalenie slova
#@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):
    if "рыжий" in message.text.lower(): 
        await message.delete()

#reakciya na slovo
#@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def main(message : types.Message):
    if "ведьмак" in message.text.lower(): 
        await message.reply('А кто это??')

async def register_handlers(dp: Dispatcher):

    dp.register_message_handler(filter_messages)
    dp.register_message_handler(main, content_types=['text'])

# run long-polling
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы не знаете для чего ВАМ регистрировать хендлеры тем способом который вы показали, то не стоит этого делать.
А вообще у вам хендлеры имеют одинаковые фильтры, потому срабатывает первый из них. В вашем случае я бы просто запихнул их в один хендлер, и само собой убрал бесполезную регистрацию хендлеров

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):
    if "рыжий" in message.text.lower(): 
        await message.delete()
    if "ведьмак" in message.text.lower(): 
        await message.reply('А кто это??')
```